# Would there be any difference for our solarsystem to be not in the Milky Way?

Tags: galaxy, solar-system

Guessing, the solar system would be taken out of our galaxy of any reason, would there be any difference to the live on earth or even to the mechanics in within our solar system?

Comment: Presumably, you are assuming that planetary orbits would not be disturbed? What about Kuiper belt and Oort cloud objects (although I suspect that will make little difference)?

Comment: I heard that our galaxy has a sort of shielding effect similar to that of the earth magnetic field with respect of charged cosmic rays. Actually it is suspected that at least one big extinction was at the moment the solar system was out of that galactic shield owing to its waving up and down with respect to the galactic plane. I would not see problems if the solar system is left to be the only object in the universe ( after the possible orbital reorganisation mentioned in the comment by @Mick

Answer (score 0):

No it wouldn't make a difference unless you moved it near another star or body. If it was moved such that something was close enough to exert significant gravitational attraction it would have an effect on our solar system.